# How to fix sentences where it is unclear whom a verb is referring to?

Tags: word-order, syntactic-analysis

From [addicted2succces.com](http://addicted2success.com/success-advice/why-successful-people-leave-their-loser-friends-behind/) the following sentence reads awkwardly in my :opinion

> He quickly noticed that all of the other friends he had hated hard
>   work and had no desire to improve themselves.

When I first read it, I thought it meant the person had hated his friends, but then I realized the intended meaning is that all but one of his friends hated hard work. In situations like this, how can the meaning be made clearer without rewriting the entire sentence?

Comment: This is a [garden path sentence](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/gardenpath.pdf), and the advice in [this response](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/75899/15299) may be helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would replace the "he had" with "his" :

> He quickly noticed that all his other friends hated hard work and had no desire to improve themselves.

The "his" eliminates the relative clause that makes this sentence difficult to parse.